# Markdown files(.md) opening in image format WebStorm

Tags: markdown, webstorm

When I open the `.md` files in WebStorm, I am getting the below error, unable to resolve.

[image]

Comment: works fine for me. Is it a local or remote image? Does it happen with all images? What preferences are chosen in Settings/Languages & Frameworks/Markdown and Settings/Languages & Frameworks/MultiMarkdown? what preview browser is chosen?

Comment: i'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching your idea.log to it

Comment: its not an image lena,this error for all .md files.I am trying to open in webstorm editor.

Comment: webstorm editor is trying to open in image format, whether there is an option to open in text format?

Comment: @user1645290 1) `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` -- find `Image` entry and remove `*.md` (or any other pattern that would match `.md` files) from the bottom list; now restart IDE. 2) What custom (not bundled by default) plugins do you have there?

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked. :)

Comment: @LazyOne may be you should have given as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`
2. Find `Image` entry and remove `*.md` (or any other pattern that would match `.md` files) from the bottom list
3. Save Settings/Preferences. IDE restart *may* be required.